# Accentuation in LaTeX

Tags: packages

Because my LaTeX is accentuating itself, without using the `[utf8]{inputenc}` packages, I've already removed it from scratch. I've reinstalled both TeX Live and TeXstudio, but it's still the same. Does anyone know what this is? Not that I'm against it, but now it's kind of strange.

Comment: In texlive 2018, utf8 is the default in the latex format. Loading inputenc is no longer needed.

Comment: Many thanks I still had not realized \ 0 /

Comment: use this package \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comment.